# android FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED equivalent

Tags: android, lockscreen

I have floating window runned as service. Floating window is LinearLayout with some LayoutParams. I displayed this window on incomming call screen (even if phone is locked). Therefoe I set as LayoutParam flag FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED. But this is deprecated. How can I show my floating window on lockscreen without this flag?a

Comment: It was deprecated and has no effect for security reasons, there's no replacement.

Comment: "This constant was deprecated in API level 27. Use R.attr.showWhenLocked or Activity.setShowWhenLocked(boolean) instead to prevent an unintentional double life-cycle event."

Comment: If there is no replacement for this flag, how can I show some window (linear layout) on locked calling screen?

Comment: I cant find R.attr.showWhenLocked, and I cant use Activity.setShowWhenLocked(boolean) because I dont have activity... I show my floating window from service.

Comment: any update you found? @spajdo

Comment: No Sagar. It's working now and I'm waiting what will be.

Comment: @spajdo Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @RajeevShetty no, I didn't find solution for this. But my application is useless, because google forbid some system api that I was using.... :(